# How could I represent this SQL statement in DAX for Power Bi

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

I have this SQL statement:

```
select ASL.* 
from dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL ASL
inner join
    (select SubtaskID, MAX(Tx_Date) as MostRecentTx
    from dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL group by SubtaskID) archiveASL
on ASL.SubtaskID = archiveASL.SubtaskID
and ASL.Tx_Date = archiveASL.MostRecentTx
where ASL.Tx_Date < Convert(datetime, '2018-03-28')
order by SubtaskID asc
```

The above is supposed to assemble a report from the given dataset as it was at a certain point in time. The dataset described is just an archival table, where anytime a change happens its recorded as a "transaction" with the date the change occurred. I'm trying to find a way to parameterize the
`where ASL.Tx_Date < Convert(datetime, '2018-03-28')` statement so that my users can just "pick" a date and the report will be generated.

Problem is I'm not sure how to do this in Power Bi, any suggestions?

Comment: What specifically are trying to do with the resulting table? I could write a DAX table calculation to reproduce this SQL, but I'm not sure that's the best way to do what you ultimately want.

Comment: The query runs against a table that has recorded every change to a report over time. It assembles the report as it was at the date specified in the where clause.

Comment: The problem is that you can't (directly) build a report off of a dynamic table. All queries and calculated tables are evaluated once and don't update if you pick a different date parameter. I'd recommend loading the whole table and then building appropriate measures for what you want instead. This will allow you to create a dynamic slicer for your `Tx_Date`.